# Identify actual precision of a float

Tags: python, decimal, precision, floating-accuracy

I am interacting with an API that returns floats. I am trying to calculate the number of decimal places with which the API created these floats.

For example:

```
# API returns the following floats.
>> 0.0194360600000000015297185740.....
>> 0.0193793800000000016048318230.....
>> 0.0193793699999999999294963970.....

# Quite clearly these are supposed to represent:
>> 0.01943606
>> 0.01937938
>> 0.01937937

# And are therefore ACTUALLY accurate to only 8 decimal places.
```

How can I identify that the floats are actually accurate to 8 decimal places? Once I do that, I can initialize a `decimal.Decimal` instance with the "true" values rather than the inaccurate floats.

Edit: The number of accurate decimal places returned by the API varies and is not always 8!

Comment: `round()` to 8 decimal places?

Comment: The whole point is I do not know the actual accuracy of the float response, I need some way of working out it is 8 decimal places (or whatever other precision) in the first place. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to enter an irrational or repeating number in that API? The examples also all have 0 (actually "0.0") as their first digits – will that always be the case?

Comment: The usual approach here - which is used by Python `repr` - is to print with the minimum number of digits that, parsed again, yields back exactly the same `float` value. This generally yields reasonable results, but keep in mind that there's no "real" way to find out "what the API really meant" - it may have actually meant 0.01943606 or 0.0194360600000000015297185740, and you have no way to know, as they are effectively the same `float` value.

Comment: usr2564301 I do not believe so, pretty sure everything is rounded to a certain number of decimal places.

Comment: Matteo Italia thankyou I did not know repr existed which is really useful and thought as much about not knowing 100% but didn't want it to be so!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.7 or Python 3.1+, consider using the `repr()` builtin.

Here's how it works with your examples in a Python 3.6 interpreter.

```
>>> repr(0.0194360600000000015297185740)
'0.01943606'
>>> repr(0.0193793800000000016048318230)
'0.01937938'
>>> repr(0.0193793699999999999294963970)
'0.01937937'
```

This works because `repr()` shows the *minimum* precision of the number, `n`, that still satisfies `float(repr(n)) == n`.

Given the string representation returned by `repr()`, you can count the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Thankyou I did not know repr existed this is really useful to me. :)